# How to get another column with aggreration in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to group records based on column1.
For Each group,I want a single record which is having max value of column2.
Along with column1,max(column2), I also want a column3 from each group for which value of column2 is matching with max(column2).

How can I make a query for this?

I am able to get first two points but not found the way to get an another column.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "column1"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "column2": {
          "max": {
            "field": "column2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It gives output like

```
{

    "took": 25,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 3995,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": [ ]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "group": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 12,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 3776,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": 10,
                    "doc_count": 27,
                    "column2": {
                        "value": 20110930013248
                    }
                }
                ,
                {
                    "key": 711,
                    "doc_count": 23,
                    "column2": {
                        "value": 20111013174812
                    }
                }
                ,
                {
                    "key": 888,
                    "doc_count": 22,
                    "column2": {
                        "value": 20110531204116
                    }
                }
                ,
                {
                    "key": 907,
                    "doc_count": 22,
                    "column2": {
                        "value": 20111013175931
                    }
                }
                ,
                {
                    "key": 1098,
                    "doc_count": 22,
                    "column2": {
                        "value": 20110421183543
                    }
                }
                ,
                {
                    "key": 702,
                    "doc_count": 21,
                    "column2": {
                        "value": 20111011183045
                    }
                }
                ,
                {
                    "key": 878,
                    "doc_count": 21,
                    "column2": {
                        "value": 20110713195140
                    }
                }
                ,
                {
                    "key": 973,
                    "doc_count": 21,
                    "column2": {
                        "value": 20111007203050
                    }
                }
                ,
                {
                    "key": 29,
                    "doc_count": 20,
                    "column2": {
                        "value": 20110927163219
                    }
                }
                ,
                {
                    "key": 675,
                    "doc_count": 20,
                    "column2": {
                        "value": 20111007001235
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }

}
```

I want value of column3 also in this result json.

Comment: Can you provide a sample output?

Comment: @Richa,edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I think following query work in your case:

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
 "group": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "column1"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "column2": {
      "top_hits": {
        "fields": ["column2" , "column3"],
        "sort" : {
            "column2" : "desc"                 ===> Sorting with column2 in decsreasing order to get max on top
        },
        "size" : 1                   ===> Restricting to size 1, so that only highest is returned
        }
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!!!